# How do I pass an incremented ID from an ajaxy php script back to form template?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I am working from an example found at: http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/

In the example they employ a hidden template for the add field html in the form and it employs aclass, addButton, to execute the javascript addButton function. The hidden template looks like with the variables I pass:

```
 <div class="form-group hide" id="itemTemplate">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label"profile_id="7" id="23" gid="100">New friend (23)</label>
    <div class="_col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-3">
        <input class="form-control  saveFname" type="text" name="fname[]" profile_id="7" id="23" gid="100"/>
    </div>
    <!-- REMOVE BUTTON -->
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton" profile_id="7" id="23" gid="100"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The php code in the form that actually generates the above html is:

```
<!-- HIDDEN TEMPLATE with REMOVE BUTTON  DYNAMICALLY ADDED-->
<div class="form-group hide" id="itemTemplate">
  <label class="col-xs-3 control-label"profile_id="<?php echo $profile_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $id ; ?>" gid="<?php echo $gid; ?>">New friend (<?php echo $id ; ?>)</label>
  <div class="_col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control  saveFname" type="text" name="fname[]" profile_id="<?php echo $profile_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $id ; ?>" gid="<?php echo $gid; ?>"/>
  </div>
  <!-- REMOVE BUTTON -->
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default removeButton" profile_id="<?php echo $profile_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $id ; ?>" gid="<?php echo $gid; ?>"> <i class="fa fa-minus"></i> </button>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- END HIDDEN TEMPLATE with REMOVE BUTTON  DYNAMICALLY ADDED-->
```

The javascript addButton function:

```
// Add button click handler
.on('click', '.addButton', function () {
    var $template = $('#itemTemplate'),
        $clone = $template.clone()
            .removeClass('hide')
            .removeAttr('id')
            .insertBefore($template),
        $item = $clone.find('[name="item[]"]');
    $('#form').formValidation('addField', $item);

    var PROFILE_ID = $(this).attr('profile_id');
    var GID = $(this).attr('gid');
    var dataString = 'profile_id=' + PROFILE_ID + '&gid=' + GID;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "addGroup.php",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false // ,
    })
})
```

This works in that it executes the php script, *addGroup.php* and inserts a new entry into the mysql table, however it fails because the hidden template inherits the same `$ID` as in the form template, whereas it needs to increment the `$ID` employed by the template for each new field added.

```
<input class="form-control  saveFname" type="text" name="fname[]" profile_id="7" id="23" gid="100"/>
```

Since the template is generated once when the page loads and takes `id="23"`, the same id gets passed to the javascript function, whereas it needs to be incremented to 24, 25, 26, etc depending on how many fields are added so that the new fields can be edited (or removed) without having to reload the page.  See a demo at:

http://dottedi.us/test/index.php

How can I make it increment the `$id`?

Changes/Thoughts:

The inherent problem is that when you load the page, that a static $id is generated and is passed to the hidden template. I set up a simple mysql statement so that the first time the template is loaded the ID takes on the next available field ID in the mysql table.

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'fieldgroup_values2'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$nextID = $row['Auto_increment'];
```

Clicking on Add the first time through then gets us an id that can make the field editable with the first Add. Subsequent adds will fail however as they will also take on the same $nextID.

This is the new html for the hidden field for the saveName/saveData.php function:

```
<div class="_col-xs-offset-2 col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control  saveFname" type="text" name="fname[]" profile_id="<?php echo $profile_id; ?>" id="<?php echo $nextID ; ?>" gid="<?php echo $gid; ?>"/>
</div>
```

Is there any way through javascript to make id="" increment every time the button is clicked?

Or is there a better jQuery method to set up an Add with an editable, saveable field?

Comment: What does `.find('[name="item[]"]')` find? I don't see any `item` name

Comment: Also the problem is that the template already has duplicated IDs for the `input` and the `button`. I guess you should remove the IDs from the template and generate a random ID at the moment you add a field

Comment: why do you even need id? You don't know what it is until you get it from server after submit

Comment: I copied the code from another script source and don't know what the 'find' does. Really nothing here. Yes passing the ID at that point isn't solving the problem, just more/less confirms that there is a problem. In the php script I do pick up a new ID but I don't know how to pass it back so that the hidden template uses it. I thought about having the PHP that adds the new field also create a template with the new ID and use that via a hidden div but that seems like an awkward solution and overly codey.

Comment: In the javascript I have:
`var NEXTID=$(this).attr('id');`
It grabs whatever I initially set as the variable for $id. I am trying to increment the ID on a click by doing something like:
`$NEXTID.val(Number($NEXTID.val())+1);`
but that comes back as undefined. Over?

Comment: I am still looking for a solution to this problem- advice anyone?